# Safely exit console-application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console application that will be ran on the weekends.  And when I come back into work I will need to safely terminate it.

It is running a loop and modifying files by moving them, and updating a database.

I cannot just simply Ctrl-Z to exit it I am assuming as this could stop the program in the middle of working on a file?

Is there a safe way for me to say press the 'c' key to set my `runLoop` `boolean` to `false` so this would exit my loop properly or is there a better way?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     bool runLoop = true;

     while (runLoop)
     {
          // bunch of code
          // moving files, updating database.
     }
}
```

What is a safe way to terminate this loop and ensure the currently running file will be finished successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily add a handler to an event exposed to you for when that command is pressed and use it to signal cancellation:

```
bool runLoop = true;

ManualResetEvent allDoneEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
{
    runLoop = false;
    allDoneEvent.WaitOne();
};

int i = 0;
while (runLoop)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i++);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);  //placeholder for real work
}

//for debugging purposes only
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit . . .");
Console.ReadKey(true);

allDoneEvent.Set();
```

Note that the entire process will be killed when that event handler finishes, so you also need to ensure that that event handler is kept running until the rest of the program is able to finish gracefully.

Comment: I added this, ran my program and hit Ctrl-C.  This left the console window open, it did stop the program from running but I'm not sure where it stopped.  I had to hit play to continue the program or stop.  It didn't act as if runLoop was false because I have it print out counts when that happens.  Is there something else I might be missing?

Comment: @JamesWilson Right, it will kill the process when that event handler finishes; you need to ensure that that event handler outlives the rest of the process.

Comment: @jgauffin escape did nothing.  And I was using this site as a reference to hit Ctrl-C. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx

Comment: @JamesWilson I edited the example to an entirely fleshed out example code.